# Responsive with Samsung devices

Tags: responsive-design, samsung-mobile

I get a problem with my client's website on Samsung. Media queries seems to not work correctly and pages are viewed in a different way compared to Apple devices. How do I make the website be on Samsung the same as on Apple devices?
Thx in advance

Comment: We can only help you if you share some of your code...